# Glimpse causes StackOverFlowException on Web Forms Site

Tags: asp.net, webforms, glimpse

I installed Glimpse 1.7.0 for my Web Forms site, but when I turn it on, the Web Forms site encounters a StackOverflowException. Stack trace is as follows:

```
[Managed to Native Transition]  
mscorlib.dll!System.Globalization.CompareInfo.IndexOf(string source, string value, int startIndex, int count, System.Globalization.CompareOptions options)  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!string.IndexOf(string value, int startIndex, int count, System.StringComparison comparisonType)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!string.Contains(string value)  Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessData(System.Type rootType, string type, object data)    Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessData(System.Type rootType, string type, object data)    Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessData(System.Type rootType, string type, object data)    Unknown
```

... cut off some duplicate rows ...

```
    Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessData(System.Type rootType, string type, object data)    Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessData(System.Type rootType, string type, object data)    Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.ProcessRecord(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel item, object viewstate, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Type> controlTypes)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Support.ViewStateFormatter.Process(Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTreeItemTrackModel root)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTree.ProcessData(System.Data.DataTable dataTable, Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.ILogger logger)   Unknown
Glimpse.WebForms.dll!Glimpse.WebForms.Tab.ControlTree.GetData(Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.ITabContext context)   Unknown
Glimpse.Core.dll!Glimpse.Core.Framework.GlimpseRuntime.ExecuteTabs(Glimpse.Core.Extensibility.RuntimeEvent runtimeEvent)    Unknown
Glimpse.Core.dll!Glimpse.Core.Framework.GlimpseRuntime.EndRequest() Unknown
Glimpse.AspNet.dll!Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule.EndRequest(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext) Unknown
Glimpse.AspNet.dll!Glimpse.AspNet.HttpModule.Init.AnonymousMethod__5(object context, System.EventArgs e)    Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() Line 4055  C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step, ref bool completedSynchronously) Line 1029    C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error) Line 3785 C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb) Line 847 C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest wr, System.Web.HttpContext context) Line 2448  C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) Line 465    C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) Line 387  C#
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) Line 499    C#
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) Line 387  C#
[AppDomain Transition]
```

Is there a way to remedy this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a [known issue](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/603) that has already been fixed, but is not yet released.

You could in the meanwhile use [our latest WebForms NuGet package](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/repository/download/bt428/98257%3aid/Glimpse.WebForms.1.0.1.nupkg) which has the updated code, but be aware that the version number has not yet changed, that is only done when the package will be released, but at least it should solve your problem.

Comment: Actually, when I look at the Glimpse WebForms package that I've installed, it is actually 1.0.1. It has been published on 28th October, 2013. Glimpse Core is 1.7.0, and Glimpse ASP.NET is 1.5.0. So it appears that I have already installed the latest WebForms NuGet package, which you mentioned.

Comment: Ah. Now I understood, after reading the known issue discussion. I downloaded the NuGet package from the link you gave to me. **I had to Login as Guest!** Then I created a folder using File Explorer and placed the downloaded nuget package there. Then I created a Local NuGet source, using Manage NuGet Packages... -> Settings (the button is in the left bottom corner). Just set the name and the location correctly. Then I browsed to the Online tab and there to the newly created Local NuGet Source, and installed the package from there. Now everything seems to work correctly. Thank you!